# columnar reporting/pivot of data from rows

Tags: python

```
(input dataset)
00:02  X 
00:03  Y 
00:03  Y 
00:03  Z 
00:03  A 
00:03  B 
00:03  C 

(output dataset)
time  X Y Z A B C
00:02 1 0 0 0 0 0
00:03 0 2 1 1 1 1
```

I need a solution in python without using pandas or numpy.

Comment: What format is your input dataset? A pandas Series or DataFrame or something else?

Comment: for now assume its text lines

Comment: Not sure what format you want your output either if you don't want to use `pandas`

Comment: without using pandas how can i get column wise count

Answer (score 1):

I assume your data is a list: `lst`. If it's a text file, you could create a list by:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lst = [x.split() for x in f]
```

You could use `collections.defaultdict` to construct a dictionary from `lst` and from that, construct the desired list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
tmp = defaultdict(lambda: dict.fromkeys([x[1] for x in lst], 0))
for i,j in lst:
    tmp[i][j] += 1
out = [['time'] + list(tmp[lst[0][0]])]
for k,v in tmp.items():
    out.append([k] + list(v.values()))
```

Output:

```
[['time', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['00:02', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ['00:03', 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```